# Sub-menu does not open on Blazor NavBar

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I've read several posts on this subject but after many hours couldn't find a solution yet.

I cannot pop the sub-menu in the NavMenu.razor.

Every solution I tried didn't work.

I even copied the example directly from Bootstrap4 as show in the code below but it didn't work.

Other than that the menu works perfectly.

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">

    <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="padding:0 20px 0 0;">
        <img src="/Client/Images/CompanyLogo.jpg" alt="Company logo" style="width:100%; height:40px; padding:0 0 0 5px; margin:0" ; />
    </div>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="@NavMenuCssClass navbar-collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse" @onclick="CollapseNavMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-light" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-light" href="\PurchaseOrders\OrderMain">Orders</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

@code {
    bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    void CollapseNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/5urmisje it's working for me.

Comment: I can see it. But it still doesn't work here for me on a standard server side blazor app

Comment: Blazor fiddle is including the js bootstrap file that makes this work. You can do the same or look at what is done in the very same example NavMenu for manipulating classes the Blazor way re the :  NavMenuCssClass

Comment: The bootstrap.min.cs is included in my Blazor app and all shows up in Intellisense. I even copied from bootstrap.min.cs to site.css but still doesn't work.